# Does Magento 2.0 has Make Model Year functionality built-in?

Tags: magento2, module, extensions

I did some research for my client in the past for the "Model/Make/Year" module for Magento 1.9 and found some that could be suitable. However, the proposal was delayed up until now, which Magento 2.0 just recently released.

As I looked into the module for Model/Make/Year, I do not see anything that would be explicitly for Magento 2.0 (from looking at Magento connect https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-2). Those that I found in the past did not specify that they support Magento 2.0 either.

Anyone else has experience implement this feature on Magento 2.0 yet? Does the functionality already exist by default, do you use any module, or do you end up implementing one yourself?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no such functionality exists out-of-box, and I'm not aware of any third-party extensions implementing it yet.

You could do a naive implementation with normal layered navigation. Set up dropdown-type or multiselect product attributes for each (make/model/year), make them filterable, and set them for each product. People can select them on category sidebars. You could also set up more advanced customization based on that.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Drop down filter based on attribute sounds like the simplest path at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can search on google with key word: "part finder for magento 2". We using extension http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/catalog/part-finder-make-model-year-for-magento-2.html for our store